# Is there a variant of jQuery's live() function that does not bind to events?

Tags: jquery

Is there a variant of jQuery's live() function that does not bind to events?

For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
$('.jdate').live(function() {
    var datebox = $(this);
    datebox.datepicker();
    //do a couple more things 
}
```

so all '.jdate' fields that are in the form and the ones that are added later through ajax are treated the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `livequery` plugin that [@jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy) (or should I say <sup>[@jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305000/jandy)</sup>) mentioned will work, I'd consider it to be a last resort because of the overhead it requires.

If you're adding new elements to the DOM, you should simply call the plugin on those new elements when you add them.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/some/path/',
    success:function(resp) {
        var $resp = $( resp );
        $resp.find('.jdate').datepicker();
        $resp.appendTo('#myform');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the `jQuery livequery plugin`<sup>[what is this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)</sup> for that purpose.

Comment: Ah, I've been waiting to see those <sup> tags! ;o)

Comment: That's hilarious! :o) I like your usage. I may have to expand mine a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You might work around this using live custom events like so:

```
$('.jdate').live('customEvent', function() {
    var datebox = $(this);
    datebox.datepicker();
    //do a couple more things 
});
$(function(){
    $('.jdate').trigger('customEvent');
});
```

Comment: That will only trigger the custom event on DOM ready. After that it will require a browser event. Overall, `.live()` can't help for the purpose of assigning plugins to future elements.